# How to give access to Exchange calendar to external?

Tags: calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013, exchange-2007

We are working with an external party and need to see each others calendars. We have tried Doodle.com, but they do not yet support Outlook 2013 (which we are using). The perfect solution would be a service where I could connect to our Exchange 2007 (!) server and then get my calendar from there directly, and the same for the rest of my team.

We have tried to publish the calendar (ICS file) to icalx.com and the subscribe from there; appears to not work (not getting updates). And this method requires Outlook to be running as far as I can see.

Does anybody know of such a service?

Comment: Can't gmail do this?

Comment: @terdon I don't think so, the old Google Outlook Sync only works for Google Apps accounts afaik

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Perhaps you could update your question to indicate which you have tried. A simple Google search will highlight a number of methods.

Comment: @JulianKnight Actually there are not so many for Outlook 2013 (that I have seen). MS has removed the Office.com link that was present in Outlook 2010 (would have solved it).

Answer (score 1):

If your Exchange server provides Outlook Web Access (OWA), you can - at least with Exchange 2010 - go into the web interface, click on the calender and share it from there. You should get back a link that you can then give to your partners.

Not sure if this is true for Exchange 2007 though I'm afraid. It is certainly dependent on the Exchange configuration. For example, this is not possible on my own organisations Exchange as it is heavily locked down.

Comment: In 2007 this is not possible afaik. I've seen that this is an option on 2010. Apparently we're moving to 2013 in 1-2 months, so then we'll propably have this option. :)

Comment: OK. Moving up to 2013 is a big step up & I think that OWA for 2013 is very good. Just try to influence the deployment project to include the calendar sharing capability and not turn it off!

Comment: Yes, I will probably be involved in the move, so that shouldn't be a problem. Thanx for responding! Appreciated!